# Should I use a rollermouse?

Tags: mouse, ergonomics

I have been using computers for many years now and i'm starting to feel some pain, especially in my arm and shoulder. I'm using my mouse for approximately 4 hours a day, sometimes more. I do think that I might switch over to an ergonomic Rollermouse. I have tested some designs, and they're all convenient to use. But I haven't really used them a lot that would prove its significance.

Most of my important tasks go to Programming, web surfing and a lot of reading on the internet. So my question is, am I the right person to use a Rollermouse for these kind of purposes? Or should I stick to the mouse? I tried different mouses as well but didn't show good results.

What's your opinion about Rollermouses in general? Are they genuinely that convenient and good after all in the longer term? How do you deal with this kind of pain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I own a Rollermouse Pro and a newer Free 2 and I really love them. I started using the Rollermouse years ago and even if I didn't experience any pain I felt the need to be preemptive about it. It took probably a week or two to get completely accustomed to it and since then I feel more comfortable than using a regular mouse. The latest Free 2 has been a very nice upgrade that fits nicely my low profile keyboard.

Some time ago I came across a Vertical mouse and I tried it for a while but I didn't fall in love with it.

I'd say that in general paradigm shifts require a certain level of "bravery" to overcome the skepticism that we all share against radical changes but to my personal opinion the Rollermouse is totally worth it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a vertical mouse most comfortable as you don't need to rotate your wrist. It was expensive though ([Evoluent](http://www.evoluent.com/vm3.html) manufacturer)
There is a lot of advice available on working more safely though. So you might need to read some of that.

Comment: An Evoluent mouse made all the difference with my tennis elbow, takes a week or so to get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting shoulder pain you should look into finding the correct position for your keyboard, mouse, monitor and chair. Have a look at the advice and leaflets on the subject [here](http://www.hse.gov.uk/msd/dse/index.htm)